# Why are my answers appearing on lifehacker?

Tags: support, user-profiles

I had a guy email me about an [answer from lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5889422/whats-the-best-way-to-back-up-tons-of-data)... I thought... Hmmm maybe I did posted there once... Then I looked and I had realized I had posted this on SE.. I looked at the registered user and it points to my SE-SU account?

You gonna tell me I should have read the terms and conditions?

Not that I care... but I was just shocked.

Comment: Doesn't [that](http://lifehacker.com/5802838/how-to-maximize-the-life-of-your-ssd) look [familiar](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/)? :)

Comment: OK-- as long as the `guys` in New York are churning the bigs bucks out of all this.. I suppose I have something out of it too..

Comment: Keeping the money out of it, it's a great way for Super User to get lots of attention from a crowd that may not frequent Stack Overflow or the SE Network of sites regularly. Think of it like this: all the upvotes for you! :D

Answer (score 11):

[There is an agreement in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119401/9314) between Stack Exchange and Lifehacker to regurge some material for the latter's blog:

> Yes. Stack Exchange does have a new partnership in place with Lifehacker. Keep an eye out for a "Crowdhacker" post published at their site once or twice a week.

At the footer of all Stack Exchange sites you'll also note that your posts are licensed through to SE via a creative commons and other sites that want to repost or slathe, should follow the [rules of attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) outlined when doing so. Lifehacker has done such.

Comment: umm.. where do i click to read the terms and condos again? just wanna check i have not sold my soul.

Comment: @ppumkin nowhere, its just an agreement the two communities have

Comment: @ppumkin If you meant the T&C for Stack Exchange, they are here: http://stackexchange.com/legal

Answer (score 7):

Even if there was no specific agreement, Lifehacker abides by the terms of the license you place your content under when posting it to Stack Exchange sites. From [here](http://stackexchange.com/legal), which is linked to from every SE page's footer:

> 3. Subscriber Content
>
> **You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) license.** You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You. [...]

(emphasis mine)

All your contributions are licensed as CC Attribution-Share Alike, and the Lifehacker post follows the [rules](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) (linked in the footer copyright statement) for attribution as specified by SE (relevant for you: they're linking to the original post and your user profile on SU).

---

There appears to be some [disagreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119301/can-i-safely-assume-that-content-here-really-is-creative-commons-licensed-given) (see comments on those posts) whether the way the terms of use are presented (or not) means they're enforceable, but that's only if you're really determined and willing to pay for a lawyer.

Comment: Yea thats brilliant- the same if you upload a photo go google picasa. Anybody can use it under creative commons if you allow it to. I was jsut like really surprised- I dont mind.. Would be nice to get more points if our posts were published on other sites though...